# POST request in Postman doesn't work when adding query params

Tags: postgresql, express, postman

I have an Express route that posts a user profile into the database:

```
router.post(
  "/:account_id",
  [
    auth,
    [
      check("name", "Please enter your name")
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check("orgName", "Please enter your organization name")
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    try {
      const accountId = req.params.account_id;

      const { name, orgName } = req.body;

      // Check for the existing profile
      let query = await db.query(
        `SELECT 1 FROM profile WHERE profile.account_id='${accountId}'`
      );

      if (query.rowCount !== 0) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          errors: [
            {
              msg: "You have already created your profile"
            }
          ]
        });
      }

      // Insert the profile
      query = await db.query(
        `INSERT INTO profile (
        account_id, profile_name, company_name) VALUES ('${accountId}', '${name}', '${orgName}') returning profile_id, account_id, profile_name, company_name`
      );

      const profile = query.rows[0];

      return res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server error");
    }
  }
);
```

This request doesn't work, and gives `CANNOT POST` error in Postman with the HTML code. However, when I remove the `:account_id` param from the URL and manually write i.e. 50, the request works. What's wrong with the query params here?

**Headers:**
x-auth-token: AUTH TOKEN
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

UPD: The error I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: How is your config in Postman? What is exatly the server response (status code, body, mainly)?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your backend controller expects the `account_id` parameter in the **path** and you are providing it in the **query string**. To make it work, change the end of the URL to `api/profile/:account_id` in Postman, removing the query string. Also, this page shows how to set URL parameters on Postman: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/